# c# Sending requst with special characters interferes the string

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, request

I send a request from one project in solution to another:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(UrlTemplate);
request.Timeout = 500000;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.ContentType = ContentType;
byte[] postData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
// Send the data.
newStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
newStream.Flush();
newStream.Close();
```

Well, in the function that is set in `UrlTemplate` I get the correct string, (which I send in the data), but the problem starts when the string contains special characters.

If the string is: `12&34`

What I get in the function is: `12`.

If the string is: `12+34`

What I get in the function is: `12 34`.

I'll be glad to know if it has happened to some of you and how you solved it. Thank in advance.

Comment: see http://www.werockyourweb.com/url-escape-characters

Comment: @ParPar have you considered marking one as answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused because the string is being [url-form Encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899297/url-encoding-form-encoding-and-mailto-encoding).  (If this were just a GET I'd say it's URL-encoded, but you're using POST.)  The & sign has a special meaning in a URL, and the + sign is used as a substitution for spaces.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.3 for the specifications.  You'll need to encode these manually using [UrlEncode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) if you want to get the results you're expecting.

Comment: Sorry I see it just now. Ok now I understand why it happens but the `UrlEncoder` gets me null in the function... One more thing - I need this form of sending because it is used by another functions in the project. Isn't there any way to force the specific string to stay like that?

Comment: Thank you, I just misunderstood you about the `UrlEncode` you gave... Now I'm using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and this completly solved the problem. Thanks again for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` or `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode` while forming UrlTemplate

Answer (score 1):

Use URI.EscapeDataString() method in your password . It will help you in getting your special character read properly .