# Are spaces preserved in x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: encoding, urlencode, specifications

In [section 17.13.4.1 of the HTML 4.01 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) the steps to encode into x-www-form-urlencoded starts with

> Space characters are replaced by `+', and then reserved characters are escaped

I’m trying to understand

1. If spaces are supposed to be preserved
2. ...and if so, how do subsequent encoding steps differentiate between plus signs and spaces if the first step is to replace all spaces with `+`?

I’m asking as part of reading the references in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5899588).

Comment: If you set up a `<form>` with `enctype="x-www-form-urlencoded"` and, in your browser, use it to post a value with spaces and +es and watch the raw request in Fiddler, I think you will see that the spaces are represented by `+` and the +es are represented by `%2B`. So there is a distinction between space and `+`. The wording in that spec is kind of weird. It would make sense to mention reserved characters before spaces, but I think this is the only sensible interpretation. It would make no sense if spaces and +es were transmitted in exactly the same way.

Comment: @JLRishe Thank you for your input. What you say makes sense. I was doing some naïve decoding in the iOS Shortcuts app and could not make sense of the order of operations in this specification. Replacing `%20` with `+` in a second pass is more along the lines of what I had expected.

Comment: I think you could simply `%`-escape everything except alphanumeric characters and spaces, and then replace the spaces with `+`. That would be a bit more straightforward than first escaping them as `%20` and then seeking out the `%20`s.

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks for the suggestion! I didn’t mean to imply I was having trouble with my decoding — I just wanted to understand the details of the encoding to see how exactly it differed from pure percent encoding in case I had missed anything. Simplest way in the Shortcuts app seems to be to just replace pluses with spaces, and then percent decode.